# Alternate a Variable Value on Each Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have some code (in an external .js file) that responds to a jquery created table cell (or column header) being clicked with the mouse.
When it is (left) clicked it sets a variable to a value of 1 (the variable value was previoulsy set undefined when declared).
Originally the code responded to a right-click to change it to a zero but I want it so it just works on left click (easier to work with in mobile touchscreen browsers then).
This later sets the background color, dependent on the value of 1 or 0.
I want it so the first time it is clicked it sets the variable to 1.
The next time it is clicked to a 0.
Then back to a 1... and so on.
(this will, on average, 50% of the time require a double-click to get the right color, I guess).

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this and thought about storing the value in a cookie (or even a text file).
Looking up the value of the cookie and then setting the variable to the opposite value accordingly. Something like this with a cookie:

```
Get cookie value and assign to tmptargetState

if (tmptargetState = 0) {
  if(key[0]===1){       targetState = 1;}
} else {
  if(key[0]===1){       targetState = 0;}
}

Store targetState value back in cookie.
```

My Question is, is there an easier way to store the variable in code without a cookie and alternate it on each click?

```
var afterSelecting = function(ev,targetArea){
    var curDom = $(ev.currentTarget);
    var key = $(ev.which);
    var targetState = undefined;

     if(key[0]===1){       targetState = 1;}   //Left mouse button to set the selected area
     //else if(key[0]===3){ targetState = 0;}   //Right mouse button to set the selected area to 0


    if(isSelecting && curDom.hasClass("TimeSheet-cell") || isColSelecting && curDom.hasClass("TimeSheet-colHead")){
        sheetModel.set(targetState,{
            startCell : targetArea.topLeft,
            endCell   : targetArea.bottomRight
        });
        removeSelecting();
        repaintSheet();
        if(sheetOption.end){
            sheetOption.end(ev,targetArea);
        }
    }else{
        removeSelecting();
    }

    isSelecting = false;
    isColSelecting = false;
    operationArea = {
        startCell : undefined,
        endCell : undefined
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This is an API for storing values in the client indefinitely and has excellent [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage).

```
function toggleTargetState() {

    // Gets the targetState item from the localStorage.
    const targetStateValue = localStorage.getItem('targetState');

    // Parse the value since you can only set string values to an item.
    const parsedValue = JSON.parse(targetStateValue);

    // The logic for updating the value.
    if (parsedValue === null || parsedValue === 0) {
        localStorage.setItem('targetState', '1');
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('targetState', '0');
    }

}
```

This function will get an item from the localStorage and check its value and finally updates it based on the outcome. Try to read up on the localStorage, their methods, properties and use cases and maybe visit it's little brother [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for this, I am sure I can use it. Better than cookie. Just got to try and get my head around how to implement it with the key press. Something makes me think my logic is a bit flawed.

Comment: It always seemed to have a value of zero. Noticed your if was comparing targetState and not parsedValue. Changed that and working now. Many thanks.